# How to put user input values into an array and then print them out

Tags: java, arrays

So my problem is, is that I'm trying to let the user input 10 values into an array and then print the array out and say how many times a user had entered in a certain value. I'm kinda new to arrays and I don't really understand them, and it would be cool if someone could help me out. Here's my code so far:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
  Scanner scan = new Scanner (System.in);            
  double[] number = new double[10];

  // User input         
  System.out.println("Enter in 10 numbers");
  for (int index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
    number[index] = scan.nextInt(); 
    System.out.println(number[index]);
  }  
}
```

Comment: And what is the problem exactly? I mean your code compiles and works. What is it not doing that you expect it to do?

Comment: This guy explains things very clearly and patiently - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html

Answer (score 0):

What do you expect the user to enter? Strings, integers, real numbers, something else?

You declare an array of type `double`, but then, in the loop, you scan for integers. If `double` values are what you expect (I'll assume so) then this will cause an error. You should use `scan.nextDouble()` instead. This should take care of part of your problem.

The other part is figuring out "how many times a user had entered in a certain value". What is this value? Is it fixed or do you receive it as input as well? You need to store this certain value somewhere and then, in the loop, you need to check if the currently provided value matches the special value you're watching out for. Each time the user enters this special value, you need to increment a counter variable and print it out in the end.

Otherwise, your code is correct as far as array manipulation is concerned. You want to store 10 numbers, you declare an array with size 10 and you loop 10 times in order to get a number and save it in the array.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what are you trying to achieve but maybe this helps you.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import static java.lang.System.out;
public class Main {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int[] number = new int[10];
    int numberToSearchFor;
    int findings = 0;
    //User input

    out.println("Enter in 10 numbers");
    for(int index = 0; index < number.length; index++){
        number[index] = scan.nextInt();
    }
    printArray(number);
    out.println("Enter the number to search for:");
    numberToSearchFor = scan.nextInt();

    for(int index = 0; index < number.length; index++) {
        if(number[index] == numberToSearchFor) {
            findings++;
        }
    }

    out.println(numberToSearchFor + " was found " + findings + " times");

}

private static void printArray(int[] number) {
    out.print("[");
    for(int index = 0; index < number.length; index++){
        out.print(number[index]);
        if(index<number.length-1) {
            out.print(",");
        }
    }
    out.println("]");
}
}
```

This would be an example:

```
Enter in 10 numbers
2
3
4
3
2
2
3
2
3
4
[2,3,4,3,2,2,3,2,3,4]
Enter the number to search for:
2
2 was found 4 times
```